# Thumbnails generated by "add_image_size" are not removed when removing media

Tags: images

I've noticed that images which are generated by "add_image_size" wont be deleted whenever i delete the media item. So after removing all media items in the media manager i have a upload folder full of thumbnail images.

Anyone else experiencing this?

Answer (score 4):

Yep.  This is standard behavior, everyone experiences it.  There's no workaround at this time.

Edit: This was fixed in WordPress 3.3 and attachments should be removed properly now.

Comment: Ah that's interesting. I was thinking about using the "delete_attachment" hook but this is called after the actual delete, so there is no data either. Then it is waiting for the wordpress folks, thanks.

Comment: I know it's MONTHS but ... Guess what works on 3.3? :D